# Regex : how to catch python functions

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I just downloaded some Jupyter python code into regular .py textfile, but the functions are lost on hundreds of lines. 
I am using sublime text and want to cut and paste all the functions on a separate file. 
How could I do that ?

Function example (tab have been replaced by 4 spaces):

```
# In[3]:

def get_webdriver():
    driver_bin = "/Users/romain/anaconda/bin/chromedriver"
    driver   = webdriver.Chrome(driver_bin)
    return driver


# In[4]:
```

I tried several variation of the following regex :

```
def .*:\n[    .*\n]+
```

Without finding the correct one :

[image]

## Edit 1:

Something like :

```
def .*:\n[    [a-zA-Z"\d\s\n.:()=/*@'-\w%éè ]*]*
```

Is getting closer : 
[image]

Comment: It seems you should remove Python tag since you are using Sublime Find feature, not actually writing Python code.

Comment: Ok, I just done it

Comment: You can't really effectively use regexes here. Take a look at [ast decompiler](https://github.com/JelleZijlstra/ast_decompiler) instead. You can `parse` the code into a tree, leave only function definitions, and dump it in a `.py`.

Comment: :-/ I think I am getting closer with  :def .*:\n[    [a-zA-Z"\d\s\n.:()=/*@'-\w%éè ]*]*

Comment: What about [this](https://regex101.com/r/psCrJj/1)?